# Any free XLSX ( Excel 2007 or above) reader and writer Helper Class or Library

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007

Now I am in need of a Excel Library.
Any free XLSX ( Excel 2007 or above) reader and writer Helper Class or Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236).  There are also a number of questions on SO that relate to using the OpenXML SDK, so this site is a great resource as well.

Answer (score 2):

See [OpenXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from MS...

It is a free library that does NOT require office to be installed... you can read + write Office files including Excel and Word (Version 2007 and up...).

IF you need more features (like rendering to PDF etc.) then you would need some 3rd-party library...